# Second tableView not loading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an App that needs two `uitables` in the same `View`, so I drag two `tableViews` to .xib file and add below code.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;

    @implementation SimpleTableViewController
    {
        NSArray *tableData1;
        NSArray *tableData2;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.tableView1.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView1.delegate = self;

        self.tableView2.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView2.delegate = self;

        // Initialize table data
        tableData1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
        tableData2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict2", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
              return [tableData1 count];
        }
        else {
              return [tableData2 count];
        }
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
           //...code...
           return cell;
        }
        else  {
             static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

             UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

             if (cell == nil) {
                 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
              }

        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

        }


    }
```

Running the app, `numberOfRowsInSection` neither `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are getting called, just `tableView1` is filled with data after 
    `[self.tableView1 reloadData];` also `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are called, but `tableView2` keeps always empty,  `[self.tableView2 reloadData];` is not working in this `tableView2`.

Based in the above example, how can I display values in both tables? Is something missing?

Comment: Have you made your class the `dataSource` and `delegate` of both your `tableViews`?

Comment: @Adeel Yes he has, in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: If you change `if (tableView == self.tableView1)` to `if (tableView == self.tableView2)`, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, do the tables swap contents (so `tableView1` is blank and `tableView2` is populated)?

Comment: Yes, the tables swap contents but content is only displayed in `tableView1`, `tableView2` continues empty

Comment: Make sure that your tables are linked to your ivars in the in IB.

Comment: Are you using same reusable identifier for both tables ?

`static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";`

If so, trying to use different identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` judge which `tableview` like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  if (tableView == tableView1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is helpful for you

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *tableData1;
    NSArray *tableData2;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableview1.dataSource = self;
    tableview1.delegate = self;

    tableview2.dataSource = self;
    tableview2.delegate = self;
    tableData1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    tableData2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict2", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        return [tableData1 count];
    }
    else {
        return [tableData2 count];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell1";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    else  {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell2";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed to set the delegate for the tableView 2.

You can set the delegate in xib, by connecting to File's Owner or you can set it in `viewDidLoad` like

```
self.tableView2.delegate = self;
```

Comment: No, he sets the data source and delegate in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you set heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: you can ask in comment section. This is not the way of answering.